# Display fields even if values are not there

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a pageblocktable like below

[image]

The column from Product to Treatment Unit Price are the fields from Product2. Column from Service to Width are the fields from Object WorkOrderItem__c.

WorkOrderItem__c is a related list to Product2.

I want if there are no WorkOrderItem__c records for a Product2, fields should appear. Not it is showing notthing on vf page if there are no records. Below is the class and vf page -

```
public with sharing class wrapper_test_controller {
public list<wrapperclass> wrapperelement_for_account{get;set;}
public list<wrapperclass> wrapperelement_for_contact{get;set;}
public string selectedproductfamily {get;set;}
public list<product2> queryResult{get;set;}
public list<Work_Order_Item__c> queryResult1{get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getproductfamily(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('None', 'None'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Bedding', 'Bedding'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Flooring', 'Flooring'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Seating', 'Seating'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Wall Treatments', 'Wall Treatments'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Other', 'Other'));

        return options;
}

    public PageReference query() {
    system.debug('@@@'+selectedproductfamily);

       // String qryString = 'select Product__r.IsActive ,Product__r.Measurement_Type__c,Product__r.Treatment_Unit_Price__c,Product__r.Cleaning_Unit_Price__c,Product__c,Product__r.Name,Product__r.Family,id,name,Service__c,Quantity__c,Length__c,Width__c from Work_Order_Item__c WHERE ' +

         //   '(Product__r.Family like \'%' + selectedproductfamily + '%\')';

         String qryString = 'SELECT Id,name,family,Measurement_Type__c,Cleaning_Unit_Price__c,Treatment_Unit_Price__c,(select Service__c,Quantity__c,Length__c,Width__c from work_order_items__R) FROM product2 WHERE ' +

            '(Family like \'%' + selectedproductfamily + '%\')';

        queryResult = Database.query(qryString);

        return null;

    }

//list<Product2> object1 = [select id,name,Family,Measurement_Type__c,Treatment_Unit_Price__c,Cleaning_Unit_Price__c from Product2 limit 10];
//list<Work_Order_Item__c> object2 = [select Product__r.Measurement_Type__c,Product__r.Treatment_Unit_Price__c,Product__r.Cleaning_Unit_Price__c,Product__c,Product__r.Name,Product__r.Family,id,name,Service__c,Quantity__c,Length__c,Width__c from Work_Order_Item__c limit 10];

public wrapper_test_controller (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

 }

public list<wrapperclass> getPieData() {
 List<wrapperclass> data = new List<wrapperclass>();


 AggregateResult[] groupedResults  = [SELECT  Product__r.Family f,count(Id) c
        FROM Work_Order_Item__c
        WHERE Product__r.Family != null
        GROUP BY Product__r.Family];

 for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {            

                    data.add(new wrapperclass(String.ValueOf(ar.get('f')),Integer.ValueOf(ar.get('c'))));

             } 

             return data; 

}
public class wrapperclass{
public String name { get; set; }  
public Integer data { get; set; }  
public Product2  account {get;set;}
public Work_Order_Item__c service {get;set;}

public wrapperclass(String Name,Integer data) {
this.name = Name; 
  this.data = data;
 } 
public wrapperclass (Work_Order_Item__c record){
  this.service = record;


  }


}
}
```

vf page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Work_Order__c" extensions="wrapper_test_controller">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageblock id="pb">

                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" />
                 </apex:pageBlockButtons >

        <apex:pageblockSection title="Work Order Details">
         <apex:outputfield label="Account" value="{!Work_Order__c.Account__c}" id="a"/>

         <apex:inputField label="Status" value="{!Work_Order__c.Status__c}" required="true"/>
          <apex:inputField label="Service Date" value="{!Work_Order__c.Service_Date__c}" required="true"/>


        </apex:pageblockSection>



        <apex:pageblockSection title="Summary">

        <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="{!pieData}">
            <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name"/>
            <apex:legend position="bottom"/>
        </apex:chart>


        </apex:pageblockSection>
                 <apex:pageblocksection title="Products" >

               <apex:outputPanel title="Family">
               <apex:outputLabel value="Family:"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <apex:actionRegion >              
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedproductfamily}" size="1" label="Family"  rendered="true" >
                    <apex:actionSupport action="{!query}" reRender="pb1" id="fam" event="onchange"/> 

                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!productfamily}" />

                </apex:selectList>
                   </apex:actionRegion> 
                   </apex:outputLabel>
                   </apex:outputPanel>  
            </apex:pageblocksection>
     <!--     </apex:pageBlock> -->

       <!--   <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" mode="edit">   -->
         <apex:pageblocktable value="{!queryResult}" var="acc" id="pb1">
          <apex:column >
          <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
          <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Name}" />
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Family">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Family}" />
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Measurement Type">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Measurement_Type__c}" />
           </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Treatment Price">
           <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Treatment_Unit_Price__c}" />
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headervalue="Cleaning Unit Price">
           <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Cleaning_Unit_Price__c}" />
           </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Service">
          <apex:repeat value="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Service__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column>


          <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
          <apex:repeat value="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Quantity__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column>

           <apex:column headerValue="Length">
           <apex:repeat value="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Length__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column>

           <apex:column headerValue="Width">
           <apex:repeat value="{!acc.work_order_items__R}" var="b">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!b.Width__c}"/>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:column> 

          </apex:pageblocktable>

        </apex:pageblock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your  values like show below :

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!IF(b.Service__c ==null,objBlank.Service__c,b.Service__c)}"/>
```

In your Controller/Extension -- Declare following :

```
// Declared to show FieldHolders (blanks textbox,picklists)
WorkOrderItem__c objBlank = new WorkOrderItem__c();
```

(Not Sure whether 'objBlank' will get access directly in VF, let us know what happens.)

Comment: where i have to declare in controller. In constructor or somewhere

Comment: In Constructor will do.

Comment: I am getting an error Error Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' ...

Comment: See that you have closed all Brackets properly. Try this for one field first,  once it work then update everywhere else.

Comment: No its giving the same error after giving all the brackets...